# How to remove extension .php in the middle of URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

Here is my URL: 
http://localhost/school-project/project1/mypage.php/home

I wanna get rid of .php in mypage.php. So the new URL should look like this: 
http://localhost/school-project/project1/mypage/home

I have tried to use RewriteRule in .htaccess, but none of them worked!

Here is the code in my .htaccess:

(this one actually gets rid of the .php, but it turned the page to Object not found, error 404)

```
RewriteRule ^mypage.php/(.*)$ http://localhost/school-project/project1/mypage/$1[NC,L,R]
```

or

```
RewriteRule (.*)mypage/(.*)$ /mypage.php?/$1 [L]
```

I don't really know where the problem is. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it looks similar but I already looked into it, his problem is a bit different. The .php extension is at the end, not in the middle.

Comment: See also: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Comment: "Any ideas?" → Multiviews+path_info should suffice. Else rewrite log. Or look through all the similar questions. There's some more useful explanations buried under the dozens of daily reposts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution for my problem. Thank you so much for all the help!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^mypage(/.+)$ mypage.php$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*)\.php(.*)\sHTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ $1.php/$2 [L]
```

Second & third lines are removing `php` extension externally.
Forth & fifth to redirect request to original path internally .

Clear browser cache then test , if it is Ok change `R=302` to `R=301` in order to be permanent redirection  .

Comment: Can you please explain this part \s/+(.*)\.php(.*)\sHTTP.*$ 
and ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ $1.php/$2 to me, thank you so much!

Comment: The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

Comment: more info here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html